# Linux / Windows Shell Scripting to Unlock PGP File

Tags: shell, dos, windows-shell, pgp, openpgp

I have a sequence of scripts which downloads PGP files from a FTP server.  I then unzip these files with a private key using PGPKeys.  The unzipped files are then picked up by a SQL Server job which appends the data onto our database.  I'd like to automate the entire process.  Is there anyway to unzip a PGP locked file using shell scripting (either Linux or Windows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [**GPG**](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manpage.en.html). In your case, it's just `gpg -d filename` (or just `gpg -d` to read from stdin).

And, what you probably wanted to say is *decrypt* instead of *unzip* and *encrypted* instead of *locked*.

Comment: Hi Marian, when I use 'pgp -d filename', there's a prompt for a pass phrase.  How do I incorporate this pass phrase prompt into my BAT file?  I have the pass phrase on the next line currently, but this does not seem to work.  The BAT file gets stuck between the 'pgp -d filename' line and the pass phrase line.

Comment: Use `--passphrase-fd`. Example usage is here: http://raftaman.net/?p=413. Under windows, that will probably not work, you will have to use `--passphrase-file`. See the gpg manpage: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gpg.1.html

Comment: The syntax ended to be pgp [filename] -z[mypassphrase]

Comment: Be careful - that way everyone on your machine can read the password (in the process listing).

Answer (score 2):

That's a perfect task to automize, I can help you in Linux.

First you can use [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to download a file

```
wget ftp://website.com/yourpgparchive.zip
```

If your ftp website requires authenticated access use

```
wget --ftp-user=USER --ftp-password=PASSWORD ftp://ftp.site/archive.zip.pgp
```

Then you need [gpg](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manpage.en.html) (the open source PGP implementation) to decrypt the file

```
gpg -o file.zip -d file.zip.gpg
```

(If you need some suggestion on how to import keys and get started with gpg check [here](http://irtfweb.ifa.hawaii.edu/~lockhart/gpg/gpg-cs.html))

Then you can just unzip the file with

```
unzip file.zip
```

You may need to install *gnupg* and *unzip* from your package manager.